# Convolving two functions doesn't work as expected in sage

Tags: sagemath

I'm trying to convolve two functions as follows:

```
forget()
x = PolynomialRing(QQ, 'x').gen()
f1 = Piecewise([[(-1, 1), 1*x^0]])
f2 = Piecewise([[(0, 1), x], [(1, 2), -x + 2]])
g = f2.convolution(f1)
Q = g.plot(rgbcolor=(1,1,0), figsize = 4);
g
```

I get that g is given by:

> Piecewise defined function with 4 parts, [[(-1, 0), 1/2*x^2 + x +1/2], [(0, 1), -1/2*x^2 + 3*x], [(1, 2), -1/2*x^2 - x + 4], [(2, 3), 1/2*x^2 -
>   3*x + 9/2]].

Whereas, if computed manually, g is given by:

> Piecewise defined function with 3 parts, [[(-1, 0),
>   0.5*x^2 + x + 0.5], [(0, 2),
>   -0.5*x^2 + x + 0.5], [(2, 3),
>   0.5*x^2 - 3*x + 4.5]

Why doesn't the one computed by sage match the correct function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this bug ticket](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/12123) correctly diagnose your problem?

We are working on redoing piecewise functions, but in the meantime you are right that this bug is annoying.

Comment: It does, thank you. I hope the newer version's up to speed?